# Sedgewick/Wayne "BellmanFordSP.java": how does "findNegativeCycle" make sure a negative cycle is returned?

Tags: java, graph-algorithm, bellman-ford

In the Sedgewick and Wayne implementation of the Bellman-Ford algorithm (https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/BellmanFordSP.java) the method `findNegativeCycle` uses `EdgeWeightedDirectedCycle` (https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/EdgeWeightedDirectedCycle.java) to find a directed cycle in the shortest path tree (the edges in the `edgeTo` array).

Also, in the `check` method, it is asserted that the weight of this directed cycle is negative. Thus, if Java assertions are enabled, the `BellmanFordSP` constructor will throw an exception if the `negativeCycle` method returns a cycle whose weight is not negative.

**Question:** if the shortest path tree contains *both* a zero-weight cycle and a negative-weight cycle, what makes sure that `EdgeWeightedDirectedCycle` doesn't return the zero-weight cycle (thus causing an assertion failure)?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be easier to write a test and find out yourself?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I wrote a property test which managed to generate test data that causes a crash. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** *This bug has been fixed by Kevin Wayne after I emailed him about the issue, by making the weight check in `relax` include the `EPSILON` constant ([link to code](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/BellmanFordSP.java.html)).*

The linked Bellman-Ford implementation does not guarantee that the negative-weight cycle is returned in the presence of both a negative-weight and zero-weight cycle.

The below graph will cause `BellmanFordSP.java` to crash (with an `AssertionError`) when the start vertex is **2**, because the weight of the found cycle equals zero (command `java -ea BellmanFordSP.java <graph.txt> 2`):

```
8
9
0 1 3.0
1 2 -3.430337482745286
2 3 0
3 4 -2
4 5 -5
5 0 0
3 6 -4
6 7 -5
7 3 9
```

Here's the above graph visualized: [image: graph visualization]

The error is ultimately caused by a floating-point rounding error.

When vertex **3** is relaxed for the second time, the current distance to this vertex equals `-7.430337482745286`. The edge 3→6 (of weight `-4.0`) will cause the distance to **6** to be updated to `-7.430337482745286 + -4.0`, which (when using
double-precision floating-point numbers) equals `-11.430337482745287` (note the ending digit is 7 and not 6).
When **6** is relaxed, the distance to **7** is updated to `-16.430337482745287`   (`-11.430337482745287 + -5.0`) which, finally, causes the relaxation of vertex **7** to update the distance to **3** to `-7.430337482745287` (`-16.430337482745287 + 9.0`). This new distance to **3** is less than the previous distance of `-7.430337482745286` (due to the floating-point rounding error), which means the 7→3 edge replaces the 2→3 edge in the shortest path tree. This results in the shortest path tree no longer containing the negative cycle (because it no longer contains 2→3), but the zero-weight cycle instead.

Comment: "_if the weight of the 1→2 edge is changed...algorithm terminates successfully_" This sounds like a floating-point arithmetic issue rather than algorithm issue.

Comment: See [this paper](https://blog.asarkar.com/assets/docs/algorithms-curated/Negative-Weight%20Cycle%20Algorithms%20-%20Huang.pdf) for detecting -ve weight cycles. A Python impl can be found on [my GitHub](https://github.com/asarkar/daily-coding-problem/blob/master/graph/bellman_ford.py).

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar You're right. The cause is a floating-point rounding error. I've added a detailed explanation of why this ends up causing the zero-weight cycle to be found instead of the negative-weight one.